# jQuery Validator Plugin - check for existing Email address

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms, validation

I'm using jQuery Validator Plugin to validate a newsletter form registration.
Following the documentation and other posts, I'm using the remote validate method to check if the email already exist in the data base.

The method works. If I enter an existing address, the remote message will be displayed and I will not be able to send the form.
However, if I change the email address to a non-existing one, the remote message is not removed and I will not be able to send the form.

Am I missing something ?

Here is my jQuery:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'my_action'
                },
                type: "post"
             }
        }
    },

    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "This field is required.",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
            remote: "This Email address is already in use."
        }
    },
});
```

Here is my ajax function (wordpress):

```
function my_action(){

    if ( !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) {

        $emailArray = get_meta_values( 'email', 'my_post_type' );

        if (in_array( $emailArray, $_POST['email'] ) ) {
            echo "notexist";
        }
        else {
            echo 'exist';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `exit;` at the end of `my_action()` function.

Comment: It doesn't seem to resolve my problem. May I ask you what  
adding `exit;` at the end of `my_action()` does exactly ?

Comment: Well it stops the script's flow, since it an asynchronous request. It is not required in some cases, though it's a good practice to use when developing with Wordpress.

Comment: Thansk for the info !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

> The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be "true" for valid elements, and can be "false", undefined, or null for invalid elements, using the default error message

Your PHP is returning the strings "exist" and "notexist" instead of false/true (respectively). I think you need to return values that the validator can understand.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected and it seems to work as expected. ( It was not the only error in my code... for example and shame on me, I inverted the two value of the `in_array`